# sql insert fails on postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I am trying to run the following insert statement using pgadmin3:

```
INSERT INTO device 
VALUES
(12345, 
'asdf',
'OY8YuDFLYdv', 
'2', 
'myname', 
'2013-04-24 11:30:08',
 Null,Null)
```

But I keep getting the following error message:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "asdf"
LINE 4: 'asdf',
        ^


********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "asdf"
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 42
```

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE device
(
  device_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('device_device_id_seq'::regclass),
  userid integer NOT NULL,
  description character varying(255),
  password character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  createdname character varying(255),
  createddatetime timestamp without time zone,
  updatedname character varying(255),
  updateddatetime timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT device_pkey PRIMARY KEY (device_id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE device
  OWNER TO appadmin;
```

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong? I've tried changing the single quotes to double quotes but that didn't help. 
I don't want to have to list all the column names in the INSERT if I dont have to.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify the columns to which you are inserting...

Comment: Example: `INSERT INTO device (col1,col2,...) VALUES (...);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you're expecting the INSERT to skip  `device_id` since it is the primary key and has a default that comes from a sequence. That's not going to happen so PostgreSQL thinks you mean this:

```
insert into device (device_id, userid, ...)
            values (12345,     'asdf', ...);
```

If you insist on not listing your columns explicitly (and making the people that get to maintain your code suffer needlessly) then you can specify `DEFAULT` in the `VALUES` to tell PostgreSQL to use the PK's default value; from the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html):

> ```
> INSERT INTO table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
>     { DEFAULT VALUES | VALUES ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) [, ...] | query }
>     [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
> ```
>
> [...]
>   `DEFAULT`
>   The corresponding column will be filled with its default value.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO device 
VALUES
(DEFAULT,
12345, 
'asdf',
...
```

But really, you should just specify the columns to make the SQL easier to understand and more robust when the schema changes.